# Convert Multiple(can be 100) Rows into a Single Rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyJoy.png)

Can any one help me to convert Multiple rows into a Single Row  in Oracle, I have a table User contains user id and Name and I want to show all in a Single row like first id of user 1 and then its name, then again Id of user 2 and its name and so on..all in one row

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called a pivot, which you can do with the [`PIVOT`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#CHDCEJJE) operator, but doesn't really work with an unknown number of columns. You might be able to do something with [Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011), but it's probably not a good idea.

Maybe you could give us more information about what you're trying to do?